# How to mock a zip file

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, zip

I want to mock a `ZipFile`.  In particular, I need a mock

1. Which passes a `zipfile.is_zipfile()` test,
2. Returns a list of strings for `zipfile.ZipFile().namelist()`, and
3. Uses only the standard library.

The code I am testing looks for potential Python modules<sup>1</sup> within a given zip archive (i.e. `.py`, `.zip`, and `.whl` files):

```py
# utils.py

import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

def find_modules(archive=None):
    """Find modules within a given zip archive.

    Inputs:
        archive (str/Path): Zip archive

    Returns:
        list (str): List of module names as strings

    """

    possible_ext = ['.py'. '.zip', '.whl']
    modules = []

    if zipfile.is_zipfile(archive): 
        paths = [Path(p) for p in zipfile.ZipFile(archive).namelist()]
        modules = [p.stem for p in paths if p.stem != '__init__' and p.suffix in possible_ext]

    return modules
```

## Voodoo solution

I have cobbled together the following test:

```py
# test_utils.py

from mypackage import utils
from unittest import mock

class TestFunctions():

    MOCK_LISTING = ['single_file_module.py', 'dummy.txt',
                    'package_namespace.zip', 'wheel_namespace-0.1-py3-none-any.whl']

    @mock.patch('zipfile.ZipFile')
    @mock.patch('zipfile.is_zipfile')
    def test_find_modules_return_value(self, mock_is_zipfile, mock_zipfile):
        mock_is_zipfile.return_value = True
        mock_zipfile.return_value.namelist.return_value = self.MOCK_LISTING
        modules = utils.find_modules('dummy_archive.zip')

        assert len(modules) == 3


def main():
    """Main function used to run tests manually.

    Use PyTest to run tests in bulk.

    """

    tc = TestFunctions()
    tc.test_find_modules_return_value()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import time

    start_time = time.time()

    main()

    print("\nThe chosen tests have all passed.")
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

## Questions

I found that a `@mock.path('zipfile.ZipFile')` alone wouldn't meet my needs; it failed a `zipfile.is_zipfile()` test.

- If I'm mocking a `ZipFile` object, shouldn't it automatically pass a `zipfile.is_zipfile()` test?
- I found that I couldn't use the same approach to overriding `is_zipfile` as I did `namelist`.  That is, an additional `@mock.patch('zipfile.is_zipfile')` was needed.  My understanding is that because a `ZipFile` defines a context, the first `return_value` overrides the `__enter__` of the context, and then the next namespace is the `ZipFile` method level.  Why doesn't the same approach work for both `is_zipfile` and `namelist`?

```py
# Test doesn't work
# Fails on: assert 0 == 3 
#            + where 0 = len([])
@mock.patch('zipfile.ZipFile')
def test_find_modules_return_value(self, mock_zipfile):
    mock_zipfile.return_value.is_zipfile.return_value = True
    mock_zipfile.return_value.namelist.return_value = self.MOCK_LISTING
    modules = utils.find_modules('dummy_archive.zip')

    assert len(modules) == 3
```

- Maybe I'm getting too far off-base and there's a simpler way to mock a `.zip` archive?

---

## EDIT

Based on @Don Kirby's answer, the pattern I found most intuitive was:

```py
def test_find_modules_return_value(self):
    # Create mock zipfile and override the is_zipfile function
    with mock.patch('mypackage.utils.zipfile') as mock_zipfile:
        mock_zipfile.is_zipfile.return_value = True
        mock_zipfile.namelist.return_value = self.MOCK_LISTING

        # Since a ZipFile is a separate object, which returns a zipfile (note 
        # that that's lowercase), we need to mock the ZipFile and have it return 
        # the zipfile mock previously created.
        with mock_patch('mypackage.utils.zipfile.ZipFile') as mock_ZipFile:
            mock_ZipFile.return_value = mock_zipfile

            modules = utils.find_modules("/dummy/path/to/check.zip")

    assert len(modules) == 3
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It's assumed that `.zip` files may contain modules and that `.zip` and `.whl` will be handled in a different process.  The file names are all we care about in this step.

Comment: I actually like your voodoo solution:) You can also use the `with mock.patch ... ` form that is a bit more flexible, if you want to refactor later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to patch `is_zipfile()` separately from `ZipFile`, because `is_zipfile()` is a function, not a method of the `ZipFile` class. I suppose you might be able to patch the whole `zipfile` module by patching `mypackage.utils.zipfile`, but that seems way more confusing.

The [`zipfile` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/zipfile.py#L252) might be useful.